# React-navigation: app not rendered when passing screenProps in TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab)

Got a problem with **screenProps**.

Simple fact of adding it to the Navigator makes my app goes blank, nothing is rendered.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
});


class Navigation extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <MainScreenNavigator screenProps={{test:1}}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in beta 7. Delete react-navigation from your package.json & re-install it.